# How to plot the 2nd and 3rd principle component after using prcomp

Tags: r, pca, prcomp

How to plot the second and third principal components after using `prcomp`?

More variance is explained by the second and third principal components on my variables of greatest interest.

Here is the code I'm using for the first and second:

```
res.pca <- prcomp(data3, scale = TRUE)
fviz_eig(res.pca)

fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,
             col.ind = "cos2", # Color by the quality of representation
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE     # Avoid text overlapping
)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. List all non-base R packages you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `axes` argument to select the dimensions you want to display:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

pca <- PCA(iris[,1:4])

fviz_pca_ind(pca,
             col.ind = "cos2", # Color by the quality of representation
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE,     # Avoid text overlapping
             axes = c(2, 3)
)
```

[image]